# Accessing $GLOBALS Array user added vars as predefined vars

Tags: php, global

I wonder if we could add a variable in `$GLOBALS` array that can be accessed as predefined $GLOBALS vars like super globals `$_POST`, `$_REQUEST`.

Example I add

```
$GLOBALS[‘_PARAMS’] = 'lorel ipsam';
```

now is it possible to access it with just

`$_PARAMS` instead of `$GLOBALS[‘_PARAMS’]`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't create your own super globals, but you can use a static class to create something accessible in the global namespace.

```
class PARAMS {
static $variable1 = 'xyz';
static $variable2 = 'abcdef';
static $variable3 = array('x','y','z');
}
```

Then anywhere in your code (in other classes, functions, etc) you can do this to reference the variables:

```
function useless_function() {
    if ( PARAMS::$variable1=='xyz' ) {
      PARAMS::$variable1 = 'zyx';
    } else {
      PARAMS::$variable1 = 'xyz';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Brent. I dont want to create supper global i just want to know if its possible to access global arrays index that way.

Comment: No. The _ has no special meaning. So $_PARAMS is just another variable with a name that begins with and underscore.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, unless you are trying withing a function.